# I need to know if an event happened or not between specific times, excel

Tags: excel

I need to know if events 1, 2 and 3, started and ended between 8:00 PM and 8:00 AM. A being starting time and B being ending time.

```
A1=6:00PM, A2=9:00PM, A3=11:00PM
B1=3:00AM, B2=7:00AM, B3=1:00AM
```

Answer (score 1):

If your times are true times and not strings that look like times then this formula in C1:

```
=AND(A1>TIME(20,0,0),B1<TIME(8,0,0))
```

And copy down.

[image]

Comment: It is in true times but it won't work!, I have tried many forms and either gives me all false, true or it does not work.

Comment: Change the cells to General.  If they are true dates they will change to a decimal.  If not they will remain as times.

Comment: Thank you very much! you made my day!

Comment: This response is correct (as evidenced by the sample image). Your 'times' are likely 'datetimes'. Change all of the cell references to a [MOD function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/MOD-function-D64C47F3-AAFD-4B2E-AE5D-C16EE3180576); e.g. `=AND(MOD(A1, 1)>TIME(20,0,0),MOD(B1,1)<TIME(8,0,0))` This strips the time out of a datetime.